# li a needs to be clickable when no sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Hi I have an accordion menu, all working fine except if a section has no subcategory I need the link to go to the page rather than try to open a submenu that's not there.

How do I implement this into this code?

```
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Store variables

        var accordion_head = $('ul.accordion > li > a.item'),
            accordion_body = $('ul.accordion li > ul.sub-menu');


        // Click function

        accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {

            // Disable header links

            event.preventDefault();

            // Show and hide the tabs on click

            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
                accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
                $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
                accordion_head.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }

        });

    });
```

HTML....

```
  <div class="Block CategoryList Moveable" id="SideCategoryList">

   <div class="BlockContent" id="dropDowns">
    <ul class="accordion">
    <li><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" >Main Category 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">   <li><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" class="item">item 1</a>

    </li>   <li ><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" class="item">item 2</a>

    </li>   <li ><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" class="item" >item 3</a>

   </li>    <li ><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" class="item">item 4</a>

    </li></ul>

</li>   <li ><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" class="item">Main Category 2</a>

</li>   <li ><a href="http://site-link.co.uk" class="item">Main Category 3</a>


</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You call `jQuery.noConflict()` and then immediately use `$` for jQuery?

Comment: post your html (menu) structures too

Comment: Try to make adjustments to your example code. Just the relevant parts. We don't need the information, where the links lead to. Also my nederlands is poor.

Comment: Also this is.an awkward style of using class attributes in HTML.

Comment: @GuidoJansen i have done this for you, I hope you can see more clearly now.

Comment: @user1475110 Not for me, you did it for yourself. Asking questions in a better fashion will lead to getting better answers. And maybe it will lead you to get the answer for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/WaQES/ change because first one doesnt have class item

`var accordion_head = $('ul.accordion > li > a')`

and add

```
  // Disable header links
    if (  $(this).next().hasClass('sub-menu')  ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out a guess:

```
// Disable header links

// event.preventDefault(); - handle this below

// Show and hide the tabs on click

if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
    accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
    var subMenu = $(this).next('ul');
    if (subMenu) {
      subMenu.stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    accordion_head.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```